# Adaptive bxSlider width or center image

Tags: jquery, css, html, bxslider

I have a slideshow with pictures of many different aspect ratios. I would like the images to be centered in the slideshow. How can I do this, or even better, how can I automatically resize the slider?

Comment: @newTag: Sorry for making you wait. :-) Here you go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For solving the center problem

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[slideWidth option](http://bxslider.com/options)

**The width of each slide. This setting is required for all horizontal carousels!**

Like this:

**JS:**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   mode: 'fade',
   captions: true,
   pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
   adaptiveHeight: true,
   slideWidth: 300
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_100/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_150/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN That is the jQuery initialization code, where we specify the width of all slides. (only once)

Comment: It only centralizes horizontally

Comment: So, to sum this up, the width cannot change dynamically. You can only set it once for everything.